# Is Maven starting two different JVM's?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project where with java backend (X), I need to start another maven project (Y) (something like `mvn test`). This works fine using ProcessBuilder.

I also added recently JMX configuration to monitor the Y-JVM, because there can be multiple Y-projects running. The JMX configuration is passed as env variable `MAVEN_OPS` and I have a method to generate **unique** random ports in range. I am also able to connect to JMX on the random generated port, from my X backend, but the problem is that this only works while the project is in building state. Right after build is done, and the maven should "start" the service, I got this error:

> [INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:execute (test1) @ xxxxxxx -- Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 15.388 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-27T09:31:10+01:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/363M
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.4:execute (test1) on project xxxxxxx: Xxxxxx failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: xxxx; nested
> exception is:   java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

Before this point I am able to get the metrics using JMX. So now, my question is, does maven use different JVM in build and execute state? Why my port is already in use???

Comment: Creating a unique range of ports on project Y, does not guarantee that a collision will not happen with a port used from project X. Instead of creating a range of ports in advance, you can create them dynamically at the moment you need to connect to them. Just make sure you catch any exceptions and retry with a different port. E.g. try to connect to 8080, if unsuccessful try 8081, then 8082 etc, until a connection is established.

Comment: I tried it now with connecting dynamically, and it worked. The only downside is that you need to know the PID, but for me it is not a problem now. Java 8 have poor process API but at least it works with reflection. Can you make your comment as an answer?

Comment: Done! Posted as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Each java program will execute in its own **JVM**, so answer to your question yes Maven will execute in it own JVM.

Elaborate more on back-end, is it spring boot or some other application. You may need to explicitly define port for each back-end. Do you require any help in Gatling context, as I see gatling logs in snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a unique range of ports on project Y, does not guarantee that a collision will not happen with a port used from project X. Instead of creating a range of ports in advance, you can create them dynamically at the moment you need to connect to them. Just make sure you catch any exceptions and retry with a different port. E.g. try to connect to 8080, if unsuccessful try 8081, then 8082 etc, until a connection is established.